# I used Wubi to install 12.04 and update to 13.10. How can I switch to a real disk partion for 14.04 but keep all my custom programs and settings?

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, wubi, system-installation, backup

I think Wubi is an excellent tool, and it's a shame it's been discontinued, but I'm ready to use a real disk install because apparently it will speed up Ubuntu noticeably.

However, I have a lot of custom settings and themes and programs installed and I would like to preserve these. Is there some way to backup my system the way I have it and restore it to that from a clean install of 14.04? If not, I'd prefer to stick with Wubi.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOWTO: migrate wubi install to partition - bcbc

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519354

All your user settings and data is in /home. If you changed some hardware settings those may be in /etc. And if you installed server type applications they may have their own folders in / (root).

You can mount root.disk from another install or even boot it from grub if necessary. So if you have space on drive, you can still go back and get anything you missed until comfortable that everything has converted.